# how do I get rid of one white space in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to print this line and the string is set:

```
print('Hello',name,'!','You were born in', age_new)
```

and I keep getting:

```
Hello Amanda ! You were born in 2005
```

How do I get the exclamation point left one space?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print. Or use any of the various ways to build a string rather than passing separate arguments to print.

Comment: Really do follow the duplicate links up top -- the answers you have now (as they were first added; things have improved slightly within the 5-minute edit window) are not modern best practice; the answers on the older copies of the question are better (as one would expect, since those copies have had more time to collect in-depth answers, for those answers to be commented on/edited/refined, etc).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

When using `print('text','text2')` you will automatically receive a space. So instead you can use old fashion `+` for concatinate.

```
name,age_new = 'bob',45
print('Hello',name+'!','You were born in', age_new)
```

But I highly **highly** suggest you move away from + and , and use `f-strings`. They are easy and efficient.

```
name,age_new = 'bob',45
print(f'Hello {name}! You were born in {age_new}')
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I am just starting out.

Comment: If it helped please accept the answer.

Comment: Upvoted for f-strings. Unless there's already a convention for other formatted printing elsewhere in your codebase, they're *so* much more readable than the other ways to do this in Python.

Answer (score -2):

How about

```py
print('Hello', name + '!','You were born in', age_new)
```